# Is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (a \cdot r^n)$ equivalent to $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n (a \cdot r^k)$?

Tags: limits, summation, infinity

In other words, when writing down an infinite sum, are we always implying that it's actually the limit of that series as the number of terms approaches infinity, or is there some subtle difference?

Comment: Yes and no, mostly yes. It is sometimes useful, in combinatorics and elsewhere, to consider *formal power series* $\sum_0^\infty  a_n t^n$, where the sequence of partial sums does not necessarily converge.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, but even if the sequence of partial sums diverges, wouldn't you say technically that its limit is $\infty$ or $-\infty$?

Comment: I second Andre Nicolas's comment. Another exotic scenario is divergent series which are meant to be understood as asymptotic expansions of a well-defined function. In this case one occasionally writes divergent series in the same way as we write convergent series, just for ease of notation. For example, $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{1+xt} dt \sim \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n n! x^n$ as $x \to 0$ in the sense of asymptotic expansions. (Apparently Euler presented this example.)

Comment: In formal power series one does not discuss convergence at all. The powers of $t$ are just the "carriers" of the coefficients.

Comment: @Ian, thanks for the explanation. I have to look up what asymptotic expansions are, it's a bit above my head right now!

Comment: Your post was a good description of the meaning of infinite series in most contexts.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, thank you, it means a lot coming from you. I think I'm slowly starting to develop better intuition for mathematical concepts related to infinity, limits, etc...Those completely stopped me in my tracks when I started studying calc; I just couldn't get past the idea of "instantaneous rates", summing up infinitely many elements, and the likes. I think it's really when I finally grasped what limits are that things started to unlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty$$

is *defined* to be

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^k$$

so yes they are the same. Of course this is an abuse of notation, since $\infty$ is not a number. In the same way, it is not "proper" to write the interval $[0,\infty)$, but we all understand what it means.

Comment: $[0,\infty)$ is proper if you use extended reals. An alternative notation is $[0,\rightarrow)$.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed it was "understood" to be the same, but to know that it's defined that way makes it very clear.